# Count orders from Today date

Tags: php, sql

I tried count the orders(rows) from today date. My output is just print sql statement. How to solve this issue?

```
<?php
$todaysDate = date("Y-m-d");
$stu_query = "select count(*) from booking where Date like '%$todaysDate%'";
print_r($stu_query);
?>
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Column data type?

Answer (score 2):

You would use the built-in date constants in the database.  In MySQL:

```
select count(*)
from booking
where date >= curdate();
```